# How to create a nested router with parameters (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to change component with react-router-dom, but i cannot do it.

I have page with parameter ex:12kb3v124j38727kguby

I go to /channel/12kb3v124j38727kguby => show **channel** page (**account** tab)

I need to change **account** tab the tab to **string/number/boolean** tab using **Link** in **Navigator**

How to solve this?

**App.js**

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
                    <Route path="/start" exact component={GetStarted} />
                    <Route path="/start/auth" exact component={Auth}/>
                    <Route path="/start/auth/signup" exact component={SignUp}/>
                    <Route path="/start/auth/signin" exact component={SignIn}/>
                    <Route path="/account" exact component={Account} />
                    <Route path="/account/new" exact component={CreateChannel} />
                    <Route path="/channel/:channel_id" exact component={Channel} />
                    <Route path="/plans" exact component={Plan} />
                    <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            <Loader />
            <Toast />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Channel.jsx**

```js
function Channel(props) {
    let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();    
    return (
        <main className="relative top-14" style={{height: "300vh"}}>
            <Navigator />
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={path} component={Account} />
                    <Route exact path={`${path}/string`} component={String} />
                    <Route exact path={`${path}/number`} component={Number} />
                    <Route exact path={`${path}/boolean`} component={Boolean} />
                    <Route exact path={`${path}/docs`} component={Documentation} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </main>
    );
}
```

**Navigator.jsx**

```js
function Navigator(props) {
    let { url } = useRouteMatch();
    return (
        <div className="top-14 w-full text-white bg-purple-400">
            <ul className="flex overflow-x-auto">
                <li className="px-4 py-6 text-lg">
                    <Link to={`${url}`}>Account</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="px-4 py-6 text-lg">
                    <Link to={`${url}/string`}>String</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="px-4 py-6 text-lg">
                    <Link to={`${url}/number`}>Number</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="px-4 py-6 text-lg">
                    <Link to={`${url}/boolean`}>Boolean</Link>
                </li>
                <li className="px-4 py-6 text-lg">
                    <Link to={`${url}/docs`}>Documentation</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: try to remove exact from `<Route path="/channel/:channel_id" exact component={Channel} />`

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka Thank you... I also just realized that the Router on Channel.jsx must also be deleted

Comment: I will move my comment to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove exact prop from your Route component that has nested routes.
Like this:

```
<Route path="/channel/:channel_id" component={Channel} />
```